# Combine 2 datasets in SQL (Athena)

Tags: sql, left-join, amazon-athena, cross-join

I have a dataset containing just ids (Let's call it dataset 1) - These are all ids

```
id

123
234
456
```

I have another dataset containing ids and date (Let's call it dataset 2) - These are ids "present" in that date.

```
id   date
  
123  02-04-2023
123  03-04-2023
123  03-05-2023
```

I want to have resultant dataset such that I have all ids on all dates and another column true/false depending on whether they are in dataset 2 or not

```
id    date         is_present 

123   02-04-2023      true
123   02-05-2023      false
...

123   03-04-2023      true
123   03-05-2023      true
123   03-06-2023      false  
...
234   <all dates>     false
456   <all dates>     false
```

I have this code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "test_view" AS 
SELECT
  t1.id
, (CASE WHEN (t2.id IS NULL) THEN false ELSE true END) is_present
, t2.day
, t2.month
, t2.year
FROM
  (dataset t1
LEFT JOIN dataset t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id))
```

I am unable to get the required view with this SQL. The resultant data needs to have "false" for all dates in dataset 2 when the id is not present in dataset 2. Right now there is just one row with "false" with no dates.

Comment: So what is stopping you? You've provided a spec but not asked a question.

Comment: Updated what I tried and the problem i am facing.

Comment: Use a CROSS JOIN to generate a list of all possible combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `cross join` the list of ids with the list of dates, then check for the presence of each tuple with a `left join`.

It is unclear what reference should be used for the dates. In normal situation, you would maybe have a calendar table (or generate it on the fly with a CTE). By default, we can just use distinct values from `dataset2`.

```
select i.id, d.date,
    case when x.id is null then 0 else 1 end is_present
from dataset1 i
cross join (select distinct date from dataset2) d
left join dataset2 x
    on x.id = i.id and x.date = d.date
order by i.id, d.date
```